# Where to find file transfer history from a SSH client (Debian/Linux)?

Tags: ssh, debian, file-transfer

Help!! Have you ever tried dragging a folder to another folder by mistake in a graphical SSH client?

Well, I did this morning, and since I wanted it to stop immediately (I could see it was about to move hundreds of files), I closed down the client by hitting X.

Now, my problem is, I don't know which folder was accidentally moved (well, actually, the client didn't have time to move the folder, but my guess is 3-4 files in it were actually moved).

So my question is: **how do I recall the "file transfer" history (or whatever history I need) on a Debian/Linux system?**

I have google'd it to no avail. And, of course, I have tried the "history" command and the .bash_history file, but I guess they only cover commands issued from the command line.

I don't know how my SSH client issues file commands (my guess is it has something to do with SFTP) so I have no clue where to find the history.

My client, in case it matters, is SSH Secure Shell for Windows.

Comment: I'd try checking for recent file modification times on your destination system. If you don't change a lot of files on that system, it might show up that way.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK There isn't. Normally all ssh logins are logged to `/var/log/auth.log`, but afaik the information which file is transfered via sftp/scp isn't logged.